# Манхэттенский проект — нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: кавычки

Собственно, вопрос уже выведен в заголовке: нужно ли использовать кавычки при написании названия "Манхэттенский проект"? Спасибо!

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, контекст, в котором употребляется термин. Без этого дать однозначный ответ не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без контекста сложно сказать. Если речь о «Проекте Манхэттен», то в приведенной Вами форме они не нужны, так как это не имя собстенное, а ссылка на тот проект.

Слова "Манхэттенский проект" формально являются мисномером, так как работы не были связаны с данным топонимом. Это ошибочное название связано с кодовым названием подразделения Манхэттенская Инженерная Бригада, проект же имееет кодовое название  «Проект Манхэттен».